# "Even otherwise" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've been reading [this text](http://www.english.dbperl.com/memories.php). The text is an autobiographical episode from the life of a contemporary Tamil Dalit writer who describes her village streets, shops and the markets:

> Then there might be a street play, or a puppet show, or a no magic, no miracle stunt performance. All these would happen from time to time. But almost certainly there would be some entertainment or other going on.
>
> **Even otherwise,** there were the coffee clubs in the bazaar: the way each waiter cooled the coffee, lifting a tumbler high up and pouring its contents into a tumbler held in his other hand.

I want to know the meaning of "Even otherwise". I didn't get anything suitable from the web. Please help.

Comment: Did you find that sentence all by itself? It certainly needs some more **context** if it has to make any sense.

Comment: i've edited. Make the sense now!

Comment: I suspect it's an incorrect attempt at 'And on top of all this,'

Comment: I found _a_ text using this exact line, and used that text to add context to your question. If it is the wrong text, or if you disagree with the edit, please feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: it is alright! u r so helpful! thank you so much! God will bless you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On its own, the sentence does not make a lot of sense, but in connection with the earlier paragraph, it does.

The author first claims that there were all kinds of things going on in the streets, *almost certainly* some entertainment would happen.

In the next paragraphe, the author describes that *even if there was no street entertainment going on*, then the coffee clubs would still be there.

*Even otherwise* in this case means *even if none of the entertainment that was mentioned earlier was going on*.